# regex: remove all but groups

Tags: regex, perl

I need to remove all but matched groups in regex. A toy example would be:

```
echo 'spam 123 ham 345 eggs' | perl -pe 's/( \d+ )/SOMETHING/g'

123 345
```

What perl regex will remove everything but the matched groups? The matched group can be more complex than just digits - I can define the groups to match, but outside of the groups I can contain any random characters

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: So are you saying that based on string segments defined by line start, line end, and whitespace characters that you want to filter out all segments except those that contain only digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just join all matches instead. I don't know Perl, but something like this might work:

```
$result = join('', $subject =~ m/\s*\d+\s*/g);
```

Comment: In Perl, an explicit seperator has to be provided as first argument to `join`. The empty string will do fine: `$result = join '', $subject =~ /.../g`.